# Write all binding errors (WPF) in file

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to write all binding errors in an application to a file?

I need that for UI autotesting.

Comment: Change Exception settings to break on all exceptions - then your application will throw exception if bindings not working

Comment: @Fabio: binding errors in WPF don't throw exceptions.

Comment: See the marked duplicate for answers showing how to create your own `TraceListener` that can intercept debug output. In your case, just write the output to a file instead of sending it to a text box. If you need more specific help, please provide a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, and explain precisely what specifically you're having trouble with.